# Android create semi resizeable box

Tags: android, text, resize, shapes

So basically I have 3 boxes on screen, each displaying different information regarding audio frequencys.

The top box shows the Note, Middle shows the pitch of that Note, and 3rd shows your pitch.

I wanted to have the numbers in a box, and since they constantly change, I wanted the box to remain a certain size instead of constantly increasing in size to fit the text. However, I also don't want to give the boxes a specific size as I want them to be able to resize depending on the screen size.
Is there a way to do this easily? Or would I have to create separate XML files for each device or something?
I will attach an image so you can see what I mean.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb5xB.png

So just imagine that each box is resizing itself depending on what text is placed in the box.
Any help with this would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If "So just imagine that each box is re-sizing itself depending on what text is placed in the box" this is needed then in the XML for the TextView widget that you use for displaying the values use.,
   android:layoutWidth="wrap_content", android:layoutHeight="wrap_content" . The wXh of the view would be adjusted according to the content (values) .
2. If "I wanted the box to remain a certain size instead of constantly increasing in size to fit the text." -If this is not done, that is if you have fixed width text widgets, then the text will be clipped if they exceed the max width.
   2.1 By above if you mean same size on each device, then figure out the maximum possible width/height on a mdpi (320X480 mdpi) emulator for each textview, say 100px width and 80px height and  is what suits you for the Note, then in the XML for the TextView widget for Note use  android:layoutWidth="100dp", android:layoutHeight="80dp" where "dp" would give you device independent pixel size, meaning the size will be adjusted according to the screen density on which the emulator is running.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and related material should help.